# Splitting a really long file with JSON array

Tags: node.js, stream

I have really big file with json array(~8GB). I need to split it into a group of small files each contains a part of the array.

The array contains only objects.

I decided to implement this algorithm:

- read a file by symbol
- add symbols to buffer
- try to parse buffer into json-object.
- if it parses write the object to file
- when file achieves some size, change a file

I tried to implement it by myself but finish with something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

readable = fs.createReadStream("walmart.dump", {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    fd: null,
});
var chunk, buffer = '', counter=0;
readable.on('readable', function() {
    readable.read(1);
    while (null !== (chunk = readable.read(1))) {
        buffer += chunk; // chunk is one symbol
        console.log(buffer.length);
        if (chunk !== '}') continue;
        try {
            var res = JSON.parse(buffer);
            console.log(res);
            readable.read(1);
            readable.read(1);
            readable.read(1);
            //Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(function(){return readable.read(1)});
            buffer = '{';
        } catch(e) { }
    }
})
```

Did somebody resolve a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Clarinet module (https://github.com/dscape/clarinet) looks quite promising to me. It's based on sax-js so it should be quite robust and well tested.

Comment: I tried to use the module, but some of the objects really big an I achieve `Error: Max buffer length exceeded: textNode`

Comment: Clarinet exposes a 'MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH' field set to `60*1024`. You can set a higher value for this field in case you run into a max buffer length exceeded error.